# Automating File Download with C#

Tags: c#

My requirement is to download a file from a site automatically, however, I have to deal with a File Download Window and there is no way I can think of to get past it.

I want to download the file into a custom path Provided by me, rather than downloaded to a default directory.

this is my code:

```
class YieldPortal
    {
        private string yieldPortalPath;
        public Dictionary<string, string> productDetail;
        private WebBrowser myWebBrowser;
        private HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection;
        private int loadIndex;
        public YieldPortal()
        {
            yieldPortalPath = "http://portal.sgp.company.org/Content/Master/product.aspx";
            productDetail = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            myWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            myWebBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
            loadIndex = 0;
            myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
        }
        WinEventDelegate dele = null;
        delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern uint GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hwnd);

        //public const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;
        public const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
        static WinEventDelegate procDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
        public void populate_productDetail()
        {
            myWebBrowser.Navigate(yieldPortalPath);

        }

        private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            theElementCollection = myWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
            {
                if (curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString() == "btnExport")
                {
                    curElement.InvokeMember("click");
                    IntPtr hhook = SetWinEventHook(32770, 32770, IntPtr.Zero, procDelegate, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
                    StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(100);
                    GetClassName(hhook, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);
                    if (hhook != IntPtr.Zero)
                     {
                     }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {
            const uint OBJID_WINDOW = 0;
            const uint CHILDID_SELF = 0;

            // filter out non-HWND, and things not children of the current application
            if (idObject != OBJID_WINDOW || idChild != CHILDID_SELF)
                return;

            //Get the window class name
            StringBuilder ClassName = new StringBuilder(100);
            GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);

            // Send close message to any dialog
            if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32770")
            {
                IntPtr hds = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download");
                IntPtr hokBtn = FindWindowEx(hds, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save");
                uint id = GetDlgCtrlID(hokBtn);
                SetActiveWindow(hds);
                IntPtr res = SendMessage(hokBtn, (int)0x00F5, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (res.ToInt32() == 1)
                    MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
            if (ClassName.ToString() == "#32768")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello 2");
            }
        }
    }

public YieldPortal myYieldPortal;
myYieldPortal = new YieldPortal();
myYieldPortal.populate_productDetail();
```

In the above code "res" is zero whereas hds and hokBtn are non zero. may I know how I can rectify this?

on the otherhand, how can I get a handle of the save as window and save to a custom path?

Comment: Why do you get a download window? If you use a `TcpClient` you get the download stream directly without a window.

Comment: I have not read up anything on that, maybe you could provide me with some details

Comment: Try using selenium to automate using a browser the way a human would.

Comment: Are you trying to get a file from a third-party website that only works via a download window? Or do you "own" the website that hosts the file?

Comment: what is the above code doing? Are you trying to automate a web browser or something?

Comment: I am trying to download a file through my company portal

Comment: Find out the URL of the file and make an http request for it? Then save the contents where you want it.

Comment: I have posted my full code, please take a look

Comment: @Adhil Do you know the file url in advance? If yes, make a [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8) to get the file. If the filename changes, I would suggest updating the Portal to have an API to get the file.

Comment: @LeoBartkus Why would you suggesting using Selenium? Why do you need to simulate a browser? Why wouldn't using an HttpClient or WebClient etc work just as well?

Comment: @crashmstr no, the file download pop up comes after i do a click in the webpage

Comment: @Adhil I understand what you think you need to do - get it like a user would with a web browser. I'm telling you not to do that. Think like a programmer and ignore the web page and go directly to asking the web server for the file.

Comment: @Adhil If the web server does some processing based on the user's "click", then my suggestion is to build an API that does the same thing - then use that in your program.

Comment: When you say "the file download popup" do you mean the browser's native download dialog? Or do you mean an extra browser window? Either way, automating a browser is most likely not necessary. Like crashmstr says, you're a developer. The web is stateless. If you figure out the necessary URL to download the file, then you can automate it, likely with about 2-5 lines of code. Automating a web browser is far over-complicating things.

Comment: When I click on the btnExport button, i believe that sends a sql query on server side and sends back an excel table that I can download, how can I get access to server side scripts?

Comment: @Adhil If it is your company's portal, talk with the people who own that website / project? This is exactly why I asked earlier if this was a third-party site or something that you owned (cannot modify vs. can modify).

Comment: If you click a button in a website on a browser, that alone cannot run a SQL query. The client side does not have access to any database servers, because what you see in the browser is running in the browser's sandbox. The server side must be called in order to do that, because the web server is free to talk to the database server. And how does the client side request that the server side do that? HTTP, the protocol of the web. So when you click that button, find out what HTTP call it's making. Then recreate that HTTP call programatically.

Comment: Everything seems to be encrypted, I tried to do a post request but i get a 401 authorization error

Comment: No, 401 doesn't mean it's encrypted. 401 means that you're not authorized. Remember that I said to recreate that HTTP call? Well part of HTTP calls are headers. Likely when you accessed the site via browser, you had to login, right? So you'll need to recreate that login as well in order to access protected resources. I'm guessing when it gave you an [HTTP 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) it provided a WWW-Authenticate header telling you how to get authorized?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring crashmstr. They've asked you repeatedly whether the portal you're trying to download from is something you can control/influence, or whether it's owned by a 3rd party. That information is important to know, because it can simplify things. Please don't ignore the question.

Comment: and I have answered it multiple times. its from a different team from the same department. i need the list for one of my automated apps, i can obviously download it manually its not a problem

Comment: @mason I am not sure, However, I am authorized via web pages, how do i provide my account details?

Comment: Instead of asking random Stack Overflow people, why don't you ask that team how to authenticate? They may even have something set up for an API hit or be able to provide something quickly to do it.